# How do I designate y as a vector of 2 functions in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, function, vector

I am trying to create a for loop to run through my program and call out a function program I have created. I have been successful in getting it to run but now I would like to simplify it one more step and shorten my program by defining y as a vector of two functions instead of y1 and y2. I tried creating a 2 cell array with the functions inside but this is a failed effort. Here is what I have.

```
f =cell(size(a));
f(1) =[@(t)  4*t];
f(2) =[@(t)   20+(5-t).^2];
```

Any advice on organizing these 2 into a vector for a single input of y?

Comment: Hi Colt so did any answer provided help you?

Answer (score 2):

What if you use a cell array instead:

```
f =cell(2,1);

f(1) ={@(t)  4*t}; %// Note the curly braces
f(2) ={@(t)   20+(5-t).^2};
```

OR using the following, which is more intuitive using cell arrays (thanks @rayryeng!). Assign the content of the cell with curly braces instead of doing the opposite as above.

```
f{1} =@(t)  4*t;
f{2} =@(t)   20+(5-t).^2;

celldisp(f)

f{1} =

    @(t)4*t



f{2} =

    @(t)20+(5-t).^2
```

Comment: Minor note.  To access each element, use curly braces `{}`.  Round braces for cell arrays are for reserved for slicing or accessing groups of cells at a time.

Comment: Yep thanks for pointing that out! Actually I assigned each function inside curly braces (at the right of the assignment) but that's a bit unintuitive I guess. Will edit.

Comment: @Colt In fact, the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html) (see "Tips") says "standard matrices or arrays of function handles are not supported". You _need_ to use another type of array, such as a cell array,

Comment: Oh I knew you already knew Benoit lol.  This was a note for the OP just in case they're not experienced with cell arrays!  BTW +1.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to define a vector-valued function whose components are your two functions:

```
f1 = @(t) 4*t;
f2 = @(t) 20+(5-t).^2;
f  = @(t) [f1(t) f2(t)];
```

So for example

```
>> f(2.5)
>> ans =
      10.0000   26.2500
```