# Editing an array of function handle like A= @(x)[ ... ]

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, function-handle

I have the following question. I created an array of function handle like

`A= @(x) [2*x; 3+x; 3-5*x; 4+7*x];`

and I like to get a new array

`B=@(x)[3+x; 4+7*x]` easily.

Do you know how to get some components of function handle array?

And I'd like to use this new array of function handle for solving ODEs with standard methods like ode23, ode45. Is it the right definition of function handle or I should use the cell array definition instead?

Your sincerely Artem

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18154053/2586922): `B = @(x) getfield(A(x), {[2 4]})`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26936960/2586922) may also help